# Nginx Configuration/Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting, config

I want to configure nginx to behave in this way :

[OK] If i browse to domain.com/, the /var/www/index.php file is called

[HOW ?] If i browse to domain.com/blah, /var/www/controller.php is called
On apache, is done by a rewrite condition :

```
RewriteRule (.*) controller.php [L,QSA]
```

[HOW ?] If i browse to domain.com/api/someMethod, /var/www/api/controller.php is called
On apache, is done by a rewrite condition :

```
RewriteRule ^api api/controller.php [L,NC]
```

[HOW ?] If i browse to domain.com/image.png, nginx display the image /var/www/image.png
On apache, is done by a rewrite condition :

```
RewriteRule \.(js|css|gif|png|jpg|ico|txt|woff|woff2)$ - [L,NC]
```

And my nginx config :

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name _;
        root /var/www;
        index index.php;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key;

        location ~ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The significant parts of the configuration would be:

```
root /var/www;
index index.php;

location = / { }

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /controller.php;
}

location /api {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /api/controller.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

The first two lines are from your original configuration.

The `location =` will ensure that the URI `/` obeys the `index index.php` rather than the `try_files` rule next.

The `location /` defines the default action, serving `image.png`, `index.php` on subdirectories and `controller.php` on anything else.

The `location /api` modifies this behaviour with respect to `controller.php`.

The `location ~ \.php$` block implements the `fastcgi` interface. Notice that `include fastcgi_params;` should come before any `fastcgi_param` directives to avoid the latter being silently overridden.

If you would like the URI `domain.com/blah.php` to call `controller.php` instead of throwing a 404, then change the `=404` to `/controller.php`.

Please see [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html) for a list of `nginx` directives.